# Does the translated Aura of Vitality form power affect only one target?

Tags: world-of-darkness, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, conversion, demon-the-descent, demon-the-fallen

The wording in the *Demon Translation Guide* for converting the *D:tF* power **Aura of Vitality** into *D:tD* rules is a bit confusing. Despite being an Aura, its wording uses “target” singular.

Is it now that, despite the “Aura” in its name, it only affects a single target that you choose? Or does it, like all other Auras, affect all targets within Primum yards?

And how long does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite the differences between DtF and DtD for Aura of Vitality.

---

### Demon the Fallen

1. The Aura of Vitality is triggered by entering Apocalyptic Form (such as Dagan, The Visage of Awakening), which generally lasts until the scene ends (or sooner if the player so decides).
2. The aura targets all living beings within Faith yards (if you have 4 Faith, then your Aura extends 4 yards).
3. All targets heal any bashing at one level per turn.

---

### Demon the Descent

1. The aura must be activated by spending Aether and **stops once the target is fully healed of non-aggravated damage**.
2. Affects **only one target**.
3. The healing is now Primum levels of bashing or downgrading Primum levels of lethal to bashing per turn.

---

All in all, the DtD version is more powerful (since you can heal bashing & lethal).

Comment: Hi hm there IS a direct conversion in the translation guide but the wording sounds like only 1 target in contrast to all the other aura wordings